# Different ways of checking for a bit

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

quick question here...

What is the difference between...

```
if ((flags & bit1) == bit1) {
    // ...
}
```

and...

```
if (flags & bit1) {
    // ...
}
```

?

That's all. Pretty sure this has been answered before, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: There is no difference if `bit1` is masking off a single bit. But if it is a mask for several bits, it will make a difference.

Comment: You have to use the first form of several bits are masked and you want to make sure that all of the bits are set instead of any bit in the mask is set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first checks whether `flags` has all of the bits set where `bit1` is also set. The second checks whether `flags` has any (i.e. at least one) of the bits set where `bit1` is also set (or vice versa; in other words, whether there's any common set bits). If `bit1` has a single bit set, then there is no difference between "any" and "all".

Comment: For those poor programmers working in a sign-and-magnitude implementation, there is a difference. If `bit1` is negative zero, then `(flags & bit1) == bit1` will always evaluate as true, even when the bit set in `bit1` is not set in `flags`, but `flags & bit1` will always evaluate as false, even when the bit set in `bit1` is set in `flags`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I would recommend using unsigned types for bit manipulation when ever possible.

Answer (score 2):

The first checks if that **particular** bitmask is set.

the second checks if **any** bit in that bitmask is set

```
int main() {
    int bitpattern =    0b00110110;
    int mask =          0b00111111;

    if(bitpattern & mask) {
        // the bits can be 0b00110110
        // or 0b00110111,0b00111110,0b00111111
        // or 0b00000110 and so on
    }
    
    if((bitpattern & mask) == bitpattern ) {
        // the bits are EXACTLY 0b00110110
    }

}
```

Comment: You have reversed the mask and the checked pattern usage. Usually we compare with mask, to check only the bits specified (the OP's example is doing the same).